# Max char length of a js associative array on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

What is the max length of an associative array on IE8?

Ex:

```
_EnsureJSNamespace('AAA.BBB');
AAA.BBB.Res = {
Cancel : 'Cancel',
Change : 'Change.',
....
};
```

I have an array that has 36000 characters, and when I trie to insert in into the console I get an error... (not relevant-> "missing : " - it is because it concatenates the array) the error only apears if I insert more than 30 000 chars, it is less, there is no problem.

Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think there is a limit on the number of key/value pairs in an object?

Comment: Limit only in memory that IE can give.

Comment: @Getz, nope, this question is actually about objects, not arrays.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi an array in JS is a kind of object, isn't it?

Comment: @LuudJacobs, indeed, but the opposite is not true. Objects in Javascript are not arrays.

Comment: @Getz On an array, only on IE8 I have errors, it does not load correctly... it's not duplicate.

Comment: So explain the error you got by editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an console limitation in IE8, not an array limitation.